# A*Pathfinding lose target after spawning from script?

Tags: unity, 3d, ai, path-finding

I have been using A*Path finding to enable object tracking. It works fine if I have both objects on the scene at the same time.

However, if I were to use a script to spawn the seeking object instead, it will only track the first path to the object and not repath again.

I am using the default AI Follow script and a prefab variable as the object to be tracked (which is an empty child game object to a moving character).

Code :

```
import Pathfinding;

//var tankTurret : Transform;
var tankBody : Transform;
//var tankCompass: Transform;
var turnSpeed : float = 10.0;

var targetPosition : Vector3;
var seeker : Seeker;
var controller : CharacterController;
var path : Path;
var speed : float = 100;
var nextWaypointDistance : float = 3.0;
private var currentWaypoint : int = 0;

function Start()
{
    //targetPosition = GameObject.FindWithTag("GTO").transform.position;
    GetNewPath();
}

function GetNewPath()
{
    Debug.Log("GETTING NEW PATH!");
    seeker.StartPath(transform.position,targetPosition,OnPathComplete);
}

function OnPathComplete(newPath : Path)
{
    if(!GetNewPath.error)
    {
        path = newPath;
        currentWaypoint = 0;
    }
}
function FixedUpdate()
{       
    if(path==null)
    {
        return;
//          Debug.Log("NO PATH!?");
    }
    /*if(currentWaypoint >= path.vectorPath.Length)
    {
        return;
    }*/

    var dir : Vector3 = (path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]-transform.position).normalized;

    controller.SimpleMove(dir);

    //tankCompass.LookAt(path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]);
    //tankBody.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(tankBody.rotation, tankCompass.rotation, Time.deltaTime*turnSpeed);

    if(Vector3.Distance (transform.position,path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]) < nextWaypointDistance)
    {
        currentWaypoint++;
    }

}
```

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does this mean? "it will only track the first path to the object"

Comment: If your tracked object moves from it's initial located position then you will need to update the tracking object to seek it's new or current position once moved

Answer (score 1):

- If you're too far from the target **and** there is no current path to navigate

  - Compute a new path to the target.
- Otherwise

  - Apply your game logic here (attack, heal, talk, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnPathComplete(newPath : Path)
{
    if(!newPath.error)
    {
        path = newPath;
        currentWaypoint = 0;
        GetNewPath();
    }
}
```